# As400 - Dynamic Sql where clause

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Where are trying to avoid generating two sql cursors because we just need to change the WHERE clause to a dynamic one.

We have one cursor performing this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE TRIM ( USUARIO ) LIKE @USUARIO ) 
AND CAST ( M15 . FECLLEGADA AS DATE ) BETWEEN @FINI AND @FFIN 
AND M15 . ESTINBOX IN ( 'A' , 'P' )
AND URGENTE LIKE ( COALESCE ( @URGENTE , '' ) CONCAT '%' )
```

and another cursor with this WHERE CLAUSE:

```
WHERE 
    CAST ( M15 . FECLLEGADA AS DATE ) BETWEEN @FINI AND @FFIN 
    AND TRIM ( USUARIO ) LIKE @USUARIO 
    AND M15 . ESTINBOX LIKE ( COALESCE ( @ESTADO , '' ) CONCAT '%' )
    AND URGENTE LIKE ( COALESCE ( @URGENTE , '' ) CONCAT '%' )
```

Is there any way to perform this where clause in just one statement:¿

This is what I've tried:

```
WHERE 
 CASE 
      WHEN @ESTADO='PR' then ESTINBOX IN ('A','P')
      ELSE M15.ESTINBOX(COALESCE (  @ESTADO , '' )    CONCAT '%' ) 
 END
```

Stored procedure is not compiling. If this is posible How could I append to the CASE WHEN
additional "AND" clauses

Comment: Can you accept the performance hit of executing both select statements together, and just using the results from one?

Comment: @Turophile - I wonder how it compares to using non-SARGable search terms.  [The timestamp at least can be safely queried](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  DB2 on the 400 ignores trailing blanks for comparisons, so `USARIO` may be able to be safely queried too (by permanently removing leading blanks or if there aren't any to begin with).

Comment: @Turophile, the problem is the large query is almost the same, except the where clause and I dont wanna mantaing the same code twice :D

Comment: @Turophile why would you even suggest that?  There seems to be no reason to have had them as two separate queries in the first place except that it wasn't understood at first how to do so. Correct, Carlos? Mustaccio gave a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, may be?

```
... WHERE TRIM ( USUARIO ) LIKE @USUARIO 
      AND CAST ( M15.FECLLEGADA AS DATE ) BETWEEN @FINI AND @FFIN 
      AND URGENTE LIKE ( COALESCE ( @URGENTE , '' ) CONCAT '%' ) 
      AND ( 
         (@ESTADO = 'PR' AND M15.ESTINBOX IN ( 'A' , 'P' ))
         OR 
         (@ESTADO != 'PR' AND M15.ESTINBOX LIKE COALESCE ( @ESTADO , '' ) CONCAT '%' 
      )
```

Comment: PR IS NOT a real db value. Just a  flag from .net